# Faster Way of Grouping Rows using Loops in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, grouping

```
For k = 1 To 25000     
   z = Sheet6.Range("E4").Offset(k, 0)
   If (z = 3 Or z = 4) Then
      Range("E4").Offset(k, 0).Rows.Group
   Else
   End If        
Next k
```

I am trying to create a loop for grouping with a condition. If the given cell (E5, E6 and so on) value is 3 or 4 then these rows will be grouped together as in Excel function "Data > Outline > Group". And this loop will run for 25000 lines, sometimes more. With my code and 25000 lines, this task takes approx. 20 minutes to run which is not ok. How can I fasten up this process? I would normally create an array to run the loop quicker but when it's "grouping" I couldn't come up with how. Bear in mind that I am using some speed-up techniques such as application calculation manual, no screen updating, no enable events. I am posting the link of an image for the end result to better explain what I need

[image]

Comment: Just trying your code on a 22k row column with numbers 1-4, with no speed-up techniques, it takes **11 seconds** to run, with a `for each` loop and an array version only being half a second faster. Wonder what slows it down.

Comment: I defined variables k and z as integers. And instead of number 25000, I use a variable called "Rows_Count" with the value 25000. That couldn't be it. Could you share how you did it with For Each loop? Maybe that's faster than For To.

Comment: There must be something in the sheet slowing it down then. Unless you put some kind of rows count inside the loop which recalculates each time. I did the For each simple `Set rng = Range("E4:E25000")` - `For Each cell In rng` - `If cell = 3 Or cell = 4 Then cell.Rows.Group` - `Next cell` that is all.

Comment: I had a progress bar inside the loop. That was slowing it down, I now removed it. It's a bit faster, still nowhere near 11 seconds.

Comment: Well there's nothing inherently wrong with your code at least, by the looks of it. I'm guessing it's not a document you can share for testing...